# What do \t and \a mean in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, escape-characters

What do \t and \a perform or do in a script? For example, I am writing a script and it goes like this \t it displays a simple script \a

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html#ESCP

Answer (score 7):

The escapes `\t` and `\a` are widely used for <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>bell</kbd> (the "a" comes from "audible alarm").  Shell scripts use this convention which came from the C language (see [example](http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/~mcba/phys2020/notes/escape.html)).

For example, they are used in the command-line [`echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) and [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) utilities (POSIX).  Because of that, you will find these documented in many places, starting with these hints.